# What is the advantage of using mapOf when declaring a dependency on a module in Gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-8

On Android, I usually add dependencies between modules in `build.gradle.kts` files as follows:

```kotlin
implementation(project(":core:domain"))
```

When the dependency is automatically added by Gradle the `mapOf` function is used.

```kotlin
implementation(project(mapOf("path" to ":core:domain")))
```

I am aware of what the `mapOf` function does, but I do not understand what it brings and how I can take advantage of this statement.

Is there any advantages of using the `mapOf` function when adding a dependency on a module?

I currently use Gradle version 8.0.